# How do you $watchCollection multiple attributes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Just like you can do `$watchGroup` to `$watch` multiple attributes, is there a way to do the similar for `$watchCollection` something like `$watchCollectionGroup`?

I do not want to `$watch` deep using the third parameter but only one level deep for multiple attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone through angular docs but no such method available but I found a way to make it possible in a single `watchCollection` method , it's just a provisional method that I wrote have a look at the code below.

[Here is a working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/J35GOUrrBSDH2GEEJUxy)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.variable = {
    num: 0,
    num1:2
  }
    $scope.variable1 = {
      num:1,
      num1: 0
  }
  $scope.fun = function(){
    $scope.variable.num++;
  }

   $scope.fun1 = function(){
    $scope.variable1.num1++;
  }

  $scope.$watchCollection(function(){
    var obj = {
      1:$scope.variable.num,
      2:$scope.variable1.num1
    }
    return obj;
  },function(n,o){
    alert(JSON.stringify(n))
  })

});
```